# Why does OS X Mavericks freeze while typing comments on StackExchange Pages in Safari?

Tags: safari, macos, performance, javascript

For a couple of days i am using **OS X Mavericks and Safari** for browsing. Sometimes while writing questions or comments on **StackExchange** pages, the computer **freezes**, and on the screen appear suddenly some black points like pixels. Not just in the section of browser, but also everywhere on screen. Then i must hard shut down the computer, by **pressing the power button**.

This happened to me until now 5-6 times, in 2-3 days. It was always while typing. Maybe it has sth to do with Javascript, i dont know.. Using **Chrome** i did **not** have this problem until now.

- This is my Safari version: Version 7.0 (9537.71)
- This is my OS X version: 10.9 Build 13A603

Anybody else having this issue?